# Null hypothesis and $\chi^2$ test

Tags: hypothesis-testing, chi-squared-test

Which null hypothesis can be tested by a $\chi^2$ test?

could you please write the description of the relevant null hypothesis or at least give an example.

Thank you.

Comment: From the help of the chisq.test() function in R :  Then Pearson's chi-squared test is performed
     of the null hypothesis that the joint distribution of the cell
     counts in a 2-dimensional contingency table is the product of the
     row and column marginals.

Comment: *Which* chi-square test? For association in contingency tables? For goodness of fit? To test distributional hypotheses? To compare variance estimates? To assess significance of added variables in nested models using Maximum Likelihood? Others?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are *lots* of things to test with chi-square. Perhaps the most common, in my experience anyway, is whether two categorical variables are associated. But also whether one variable fits a certain distribution. It can also come up in testing of various models.

Comment: The question is about the mathematical statement of $H_0$, I think (the mathematical definition of "association" here)

Answer (score -1):

It is used to check if a given sample is of a certain law (goodness-of-fit test), and it's also used to check whether to samples are independent.
Here's an example using R

```
x=rnorm(100)
y=rnorm(100)
chisq.test(x,y) # test for goodness of fit
```

HTH

Comment: As it is stated in http://www.charlesdennishale.com/books/eets_ap/13_Statistical_Fdn_Nominal_Ordinal_Data_Analysis.pdf Chi-square can be used to test whether a. Observed nominal data conforms to some theoretical or expected distribution b. Two variables within a sample are related c. Two or more samples, drawn from different populations, are homogenous on some characteristic of interest

Comment: David: and so, what is $H_0$ ?

Comment: $H_0$ is : $x$ and $y$ come from the same $mother$ distribution , you do not even have to specify the distribution is normal or anything. You can view it as a distance between the empirical cumulative density functions of the two input samples. Is it clear?

Comment: This is a mis-application of `chisq.test` and its output is nonsensical.  According to its manual page, "Otherwise, x and y must be vectors or factors of the same length; cases with missing values are removed, the objects are coerced to factors, and the contingency table is computed from these." In short, these data are supposed to represent a small contingency table. In the application given here, it's virtually certain that all $(x,y)$ pairs will be distinct, leading to a $100$ by $100$ table with $99$ zeros in each row and each column!

Comment: This is wrong...